# How to Find the first character of a string in array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

suppose...

```
string[] array = { "one", "two", "three" };
```

how can I access the first character of `string` inside an array?

Example: 't' of `"two"`.

Comment: What do you expect, an array of strings or characters containing just the first character?

Comment: i want to make a program in which users gives a char and program prints the words starting from that char...

Comment: words are stored in array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work. There are a variety of string operators you can use, but here's a variation:

```
string[] array = {"one","two","three"};

foreach(string word in array) {
   Console.WriteLine(word.Substring(0,1));
}
```

Also simply, word[0] would work.

Comment: Or `word[0]` instead of `word.Substring(0,1)`

Answer (score 1):

Although LINQ is overcomplicated for this, consider the null and empty cases:

```
string[] array = { "one", "two", "three", null, string.Empty };
array.Select(s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? null : s.Substring(0, 1))
```

This will return `["o","t","t",null,null]` rather than throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
const numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
 
const startsWithT = numbers.findIndex(num => {
  return num[0] === 't' ? true : false;
});
console.log(startsWithT); //return 2
```

With this, we can find out the first string in the array that starts with 'T'.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
array.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).Select(c => c[0]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use array[0][0] will give you the o of one. Just vary the first index for the one you want. Array[i][0] with i the index of the element in the array